# Loop array data rows by row in table

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, arraylist

I have two arrays.

`var TableData:Array< String > = Array < String >()
 var TableSpeed:Array< String > = Array < String >()`

Each array Name, title, Address and Age are involved. 
I would like to display that four datas together row by row.
My current problem is that each data appears in each row.
**"Name"** displays in first row.
 **"Title"** data displays in second row.

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let packCellToReturn = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("packCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PackTableViewCell

    switch (packSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
    case 0:
        packCellToReturn.lblName.text = TableData[indexPath.row]
        packCellToReturn.lblTitle.text = TableData[indexPath.row]
        packCellToReturn.lblAddress.text = TableData[indexPath.row]
        packCellToReturn.lblAge.text = TableData[indexPath.row]

        break
    case 1:
        packCellToReturn.lblName.text = TableSpeed[indexPath.row]
        packCellToReturn.lblTitle.text = TableSpeed[indexPath.row]
        packCellToReturn.lblAddress.text = TableSpeed[indexPath.row]
        packCellToReturn.lblAge.text = TableSpeed[indexPath.row]
        break
    default:
        break

    }

    return packCellToReturn


}
```

Comment: 1: Please simply use `var TableData = [String]()` instead of `var TableData:Array< String > = Array < String >()` 2: please use camel case variable names: `tableData` 3: you do realize that your code always assigns the ***same*** value to all 4 labels!? 4: dont split the data amongst multiple arrays, create a struct or class holding all values of *one* object together! What exactly do you want to achieve and what exactly is happening instead?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve, but I think you need to rethink your data structure.

At the moment, you're accessing the entire array with this code, which means that the .lblName property as well as the other three are all set to the entire array.

```
packCellToReturn.lblName.text = TableData[indexPath.row]
```

I would try implementing it like this:

```
struct TableData {

var name
var title
var address
var age

/*
Here you can either set up a memberwise initializer as I did below, or set default values for each variable above.
init(String: name, String: title, String: address, Int: age) {
self.name = name
self.title = title
self.address = address
self.age = age
*/
}

//Creating an array of TableData elements.
var tableData = [TableData]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let packCellToReturn = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("packCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PackTableViewCell

switch (packSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
{
case 0:
    packCellToReturn.lblName.text = tableData[indexPath.row].name
    packCellToReturn.lblTitle.text = tableData[indexPath.row].title
    packCellToReturn.lblAddress.text = tableData[indexPath.row].address
    packCellToReturn.lblAge.text = tableData[indexPath.row].age

    break
```

And then do the same thing with creating the structure etc. for the TableSpeed struct and a tableSpeed array of TableSpeed structs and implement it similarly in the tableView func.